# How to use PageView with Stack?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

I'm new to Flutter and I like the PageView widget, but how do I always have an AppBar or other elements on top?
Now PageView is changing the entire page, along with the AppBar, how can you pin it? To make the pages scroll under the AppBar

```
Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
      FutureBuilder(
          future: _futureMenu,
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              return PageView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                  return PageForPosition();
                },
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length, // Can be null
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError){

            }
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Please provide some code or snippet. Your question is not clear

Comment: I inserted part of the code, I need the AppBar to always be on the screen (not moving along with the PageView), as if the first layer of the application

Comment: Is that a requirement that you want to use a stack? rather that appBar?

Comment: I changed the example, so it is more clear what I want to get as a result

Comment: In my example, I want the Container to be on top of all pages, but it is hidden behind the PageView

Comment: I understand, please be refered to my answer. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Place the `AppBar` widget in scaffold appBar parameter.

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),//<-- Move appbar here.
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      FutureBuilder(
          future: _futureMenu,
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              return PageView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                  return PageForPosition();
                },
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length, // Can be null
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError){
               return Center(child:Text('Error'));
            }
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Check this [dart pad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/85a9e16e06c4ddee9f2844bbdf0e77d8).

Answer (score 0):

You could try use sliverAppbar code like this

```
SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 300.0,
              pinned: true,
```

Pinned allows it to stay fixed to the top if you need additional help on this way of creating an app bar let me know happy to help further explain

Answer (score 0):

You can use CustomScrollView like below to gain your UI and effect.

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    const SliverAppBar(
      pinned: true,
      expandedHeight: 250.0,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
    ),
    SliverGrid(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
        childAspectRatio: 4.0,
      ),
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.teal[100 * (index % 9)],
            child: Text('Grid Item $index'),
          );
        },
        childCount: 20,
      ),
    ),
    SliverFixedExtentList(
      itemExtent: 50.0,
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.lightBlue[100 * (index % 9)],
            child: Text('List Item $index'),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```